# Multiple tables in one worksheet - how do I gather important info onto another worksheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Hope this doesn't sound too confusing:

I have an Excel workbook consisting of 5 worksheets. First 4 worksheets contain data that has been manually entered over the last 4 years.

The 5th worksheet contains roughly 70 tables that I created that combines data (financials) from the first four worksheets using `SUMIFS` (e.g. if column 1 contains 'Joe Smith' combine total money in column 3 pertaining to Joe Smith), and financial data manually entered from other sources not present in the previous 4 worksheets.

I want to create a new worksheet that will now give me condensed info (like name and Financials from company 1, financials from company 2, and final financial totals)

In addition, I would like to be able to total financial sources, and amounts as well.

Can I segregate each table in the 5th worksheet? Is there a way each table can be labelled "table 1" or "Joe Smith Table"... or do I have to use `SUMIFS` for this worksheet as well?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question but named ranges might be what you need.
You can give a single cell or group of cells a specific name and refer to that name in formulas instead of using the cell address.
In Excel 2007 it's in the formulas tab, hopefully it's still there in 2010.

Comment: I think that might work. On my next sheet, can I use pivot tables and include info from each labelled range of cells?

Comment: Disclaimer: I haven't used pivot tables in about 4 years and even then I only used them to learn to use them.
I see no reason why this wouldn't work if you create a new pivot table, once the create pivot table dialogue is open you can still use the ribbon even though _most_ things are greyed out, go to the **Formulas tab** and in the **Defined Names** group the **Use In Formula** button will still be available, click this to use a named range as the source for the pivot table.